# C++ container and == operator for symmetric matrix

Tags: c++, data-structures, matrix

Here is part of my code dealing with symmetrix matrices:

```
SymmetricMatrix<std::deque<int> > a(3);
SymmetricMatrix<std::list<int> > b(3);
SymmetricMatrix<std::vector<int> > c(4);
SymmetricMatrix<std::list<int> > d(3);

a(1,1) = b(1,1) = c(1,1) = d(1,1) = 7;
a(1,2) = b(2,1) = c(1,2) = d(2,2) = 3;

if(b == c) {}
```

What kind of container or data structure do you suggest to use to implement the `SymmetricMatrix` class? (I have tried `std::vector`) Also, how could I implement the == operator? Now, it works for b == d, but not for a == b (`no match for 'operator =='`).

Comment: Do you plan on these Matrices growing, or are their dimensions static over their lifetime?

Comment: The dimensions are static.

Comment: If static use std::vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the `==` is undefined on `a == b` is because the classes `SymmetricMatrix<std::deque<int> >` and `SymmetricMatrix<std::list<int> >` are of different types. An operator `==` defined inside one of them is not going to apply.

However, C++ lets you define "free-standing" operator templates, like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(const SymmetricMatrix<T>& lhs, const SymmetricMatrix<U>& rhs) {
    // Do the comparison here
}
```

This operator takes references to `SymmetricMatrix` objects with different type arguments, so the compiler will be able to call it for `a == b`. You may need to declare "friendship" to this operator inside your `SymmetricMatrix` template in order to let the operator access private and protected members of the matrix class.